# rails, form select, pluck 2 fields

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, select, activerecord, pluck

I'm trying to simply display 2 fields (first name and last name) in a form select (f.select). Here is my code:

```
<%= f.select :person, User.where(verified_person: 't').pluck(:first_name, :last_name) %>
```

With the code above, the select drop-down field only displays first name. I'm using Active Record 4.2 and Rails 4. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try Using This Code:

```
<%=f.select :person, options_for_select(User.where(verified_person: 't').collect {|user| ["#{user.first_name} - #{user.last_name}", user.first_name] }), :include_blank => true%>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this.. seems to work for me:

```
<%= f.select(:person) do %>
  <% User.where(verified_person: 't').each do |user| -%>
    <%= content_tag(:option, user.first_name + " " + user.last_name, value: user.id) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```